# Google Discovery based API :: unable to create API client (SCOPES error)

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-oauth, airflow

I'm trying to build custom hook, in order to connect to Google's APIs only supported by [Google API Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained#google_cloud_client_libraries) (not by [Google Cloud Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained#google_cloud_client_libraries), unfortunately!)

Here's my code for authentication part to the service:

```py
class MyGoogleDiscoveryServiceHook(GoogleCloudBaseHook):
    client = None
    serviceName = "analyticsreporting"
    version = "v4"
    def __init__(self, conn_id = None, delegate_to = None):
        super().__init__(conn_id,delegate_to)
        self.conn_id = self.get_connection("google_analytics")
        self.extras = self.conn_id.extra_dejson
        self.KEY_FILE_LOC = self.extras.get("extra__google_cloud_platform__key_path")
        self.SCOPES = self.extras.get("extra__google_cloud_platform__scope")

    def get_conn(self):
        if not self.client:
            from google.oauth2 import service_account
            credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(filename = self.KEY_FILE_LOC,
                                         scopes = self.SCOPES)
            from googleapiclient.errors import Error
            self.client = build(self.serviceName, self.version,
                                #http=http_authorized,
                                #credentials = None,
                                http=None,
                                credentials = credentials,
                                cache_discovery=False,
                                )
        return self.client
```

However when I use this hook in my custom operator, I get the ERROR:

> [2019-12-10 21:43:41,577] {taskinstance.py:1058} ERROR - ('invalid_scope: h is not a valid audience string.', '{\n  "error": "invalid_scope",\n  "error_description": "h is not a valid audience string."\n}')

I'm pretty sure, in Airflow Connections settings I've input correct scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly` and the DAG is reading Scopes correctly from Airflow Connection string.

can anyone advice what could be wrong here ?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE-1**: attaching Airflow Connection:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is the `scopes` value you're getting from extras is a plain string, not  a tuple/list. The default scopes value in `GoogleCloudBaseHook` hints at the expected format (https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.5/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_api_base_hook.py#L37):

```
_DEFAULT_SCOPES = ('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',)
```

The error message further enforces this, as it seems to be trying to access the index zero of what you're passing in, which in the case of your string is the `h` the error is complaining about.

Comment: Thanks for pointing.. you're correct. `self.conn_id.extra_dejson` reads all key values as text string, where as `Credentials.from_service_account_file` method expects scopes in tuple/list format. I fixed and it's working now as expected